# Intervals of increase /decrease

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions

I would like to find the intervals on which the function
$$\frac{-4x}{x^2-1},$$
increases and decrease, but I am not sure how? Could somebody help me? 
My textbook it says to first find the intervals and then the critical points. I have no clue how to do this, however.

Comment: You should already be acquainted with how to discuss the sign of a fraction, are you not?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a critical point?

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)=\frac{-4x}{x^2-1}$ , then $f'(x)=\frac{4+4x^2}{(x^2-1)^2}$

($x \ne 1$).

Hence $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \ne 1$.

Conclusion ?

Comment: The equation that i wrote is already deviated...

Comment: It says that  f′(x)>0 for x not being equal to -1 and f'(x) smaller than 0 when x is not equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

You have to study the sign of the derivative:
$$
f'(x)=\frac{-4x}{(x+1)(x-1)}
$$
is positive when $x<-1$ or $0\le x < 1$, is negative when $-1< x \le 0$ or $x>1$, and is null when $x=0$.

So there is a local minimum in $x=0$.